# Ошибка при отправки рандомного видео telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

```
if message.text == 'video':
    ids = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
    bot.send_video(message.chat.id, random.choice(ids))
```

при выполнении команды выдаёт такую ошибку:

> ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The
> server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
> [b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: type of
> file mismatch"}']"

использую telebot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telegram ожидает файл. [документация](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendvideo)

Вот пример отправки gif:

```
img = open('/files/GIF/test.gif', 'rb')
bot.send_video(message.chat.id, img, None, 'Caption')
img.close()
```